# Android how to create a folder on sd-card?

Tags: android, permissions, directory, android-sdcard

On my StartActivity, I want to create a Folder for the App on my SD-Card. Now first I set the permission at the manifest.xml like this

`<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Than I write some code at `onCreate` Method on my StartActivity like this

```
//Creat an AppFolder
    String appPathString = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/MyIdea";
    try {
        File appPath = new File(appPathString);
        if (!appPath.exists()) {
            appPath.mkdirs();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Folder created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("saveToExternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Now I run the app on my Nexus 5 the app start and the toast is showing. But if I go on my device, I can't find any folder which the name, that is beeing created. What is wrong ?

Comment: Are you getting an Exception? You might be running into problems with the [new(ish) storage API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html).

Comment: Hi Knossos, I 've run the code-snippet with the debugger and i don't get an Exception. Have you an idea, what the problem is and how can I solve it?

Comment: Try to print absolute path of your folder in Toast to see where exactly is the folder.

Comment: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), appPath.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); shows: /storage/emulated/0/MyIdea

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It works for me . You need to point to `AbsolutePath` of storage

```
String state;
state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if ((Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED).equals(state)) {
                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File Dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/My Ideas");
                if (!Dir.exists()) {
                    Dir.mkdir();

                }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I copy and paste that code but nothing happened. There is no folder My Ideas @ /storage/emulated/0. I think something is wrong with permissions, but i get no Exception.

Comment: I guess problem is somewhere else. Please post your onCreate function. You can also try to debug code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just wondering, ( I know, we don't write anything) but please give a try to call appPath.flush(); and appPath.close();

and when I'm adding the WRITE permission, I also adding the READ, just to make sure !

```
    <uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I've tryed this, but nothing happens. How about the settings on my device and the settings on android studio? Could be they wrong?

Comment: try this: getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Answer (score 0):

After a short search i found, that I need special uses-permissions for android sdk 23. So I change my android

`<uses-permission-sdk-23
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="23"
        />`
Now it works fine. Thanks all for support!